# Using RMI, is it possible to de-serialized object(of class not in current JVM classpath) and transfer to other JVM which contains this class

Tags: java, inputstream, rmi, xml-deserialization

I have a serialized object in 
    java.io.InputStream and I do not have this class in my current JVM classpath. Is it possible to retrieve this object using 
    java.beans.XMLDecoder(with out adding the class to the classpath) and pass it to a different JVM (usign RMI) which contains this class.
 
  Thanks in Advance.

Example Code:

```
java.beans.XMLDecoder decoder = new java.beans.XMLDecoder(inputStream);
Object object = decoder.readObject();
decoder.close();
return object;
```

Comment: A Serialized object is just a sequence of bytes. What is the purpose of the XMLDecoder here? Are you putting the bytes in an XML element?

Comment: Added code snippet as example.

Comment: Then you re-serialize this object to send it to the other JVM?

Comment: Why bother to deserialize? Just pass the raw bytes to the destination.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you going to cast your object in the destination VM?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I agree with SotiriosDelimanolis and @Jim, the 2 JVM's are Client and Server. I want to handle all the code at server JVM and send only the object to Client. By casting the object I mean explicit casting.

Comment: Then what you are asking is impossible. You will get a ClassNotFoundException when the JVM *loads the class containing the cast.* Long before it gets anywhere near doing any deserializing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't deserialize any object unless you have the corresponding class available.